# How do I extract the domain with a hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract the domain with a hash without the long random id from the location address bar to make it to show like this:

```
http://test.example.com/#inbox
```

Here is the full URL:

```
http://test.example.com/#inbox/U2FsdGVkX19stSSdMXLZq5v7bOgzRLtaM7Lr1t+lWpI=
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var url = location.hash.split('#inbox')[1];
```

And I have also tried this:

```
var url = $(location).attr("href").split('/')[2];
```

Unfortunately, I didn't get what I want to extract the domain and the hash without the long random id.

When I try it, it extracts the domain name and the hash without the random id to get the return output for the URL like `http://test.example.com/#inbox`.

Comment: If the hash always only contains a single slash and you want to remove everything after that slash, you can just do `location.href.slice(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/'))`

Comment: @FelixKling code will look for the last slash and then save everything before it. It looks like what you're trying to get rid of is randomly generated code to prevent caching issues, so it should always be the last part of the URL.

Comment: If url is the full link including id, then use url.substr(0, url.indexOf(“#”)) + “#inbox”

Comment: Wait what is it you want exactly? To retrieve this string or to set this new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the whole URL, found where the "#" is, added 6 to its count for "#" + the word "inbox", and dropped the rest of the URL:

```
var url = document.URL;
var i = url.indexOf('#') + 6; // 6 is length of "#" + the word "inbox"
var answer = url.substr(0, i);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `indexOf()` to find the position of the `'#'` character. Since the URL can't include a `'#'`, it is safe to assume that the first `'#'` will be the one you're interested in.

Then I would search for the `'/'`, again with `indexOf()`, so the word between the `'#'` and the `'/'` can change and things still work as expected.

That position is the location of the `'/'` and anything before that can be returned which is what the `String.sub()` function does and it returns that URL you're looking for:

```
var pos = location.href.indexOf('#')
pos = location.href.indexOf('/', pos)
var url = location.href.substr(0, pos)
```

Another way, although I'm not sure whether it's fully portable, is to use the location fields like so:

```
var url = location.origin + location.pathname + "#inbox"
```

If the `"#inbox"` part can change, you may be able to tweak the code or search for a slash in `location.hash` like so:

```
var pos = location.hash.indexOf('/')
var url = location.origin + location.pathname + location.hash.sub(0, pos)
```

Either way should be plenty fast anyway (especially since you won't need to loop over such).

Answer (score -2):

Try the code below:

```
// Complete URL
var url = 'http://test.example.com/#inbox/U2FsdGVkX19stSSdMXLZq5v7bOgzRLtaM7Lr1t+lWpI=';

var desiredResult = url.match(/.*\/\#inbox\//)[0];
console.log(desiredResult.substring(0, desiredResult.length - 1)); // this will output 'http://test.example.com/#inbox'
```

Comment: What is `url` in your example?

Comment: arifulh there's a discussion here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384528/how-do-you-deal-with-an-edit-which-completely-changes-the-code-of-an-answer if you'd like to look when you come back.